# How to access python list and save it as a string

Tags: python, list

I want a single string which contains three list data

Like

```
 list_1 = ['Modified', 'Modified', 'Added', 'Added']
 list_2 = ['92', '92', '92', '92'] 
 list_3 = ['trunk/new','trunk', 'branch','oldpath']
```

My string should be like:

```
 "Modified/92 trunk/new 
  Modified/92 trunk
  Added/92 branch
  Added/92 oldpath"
```

How to add these list get this kind of string?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and some [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) here:

```
>>> s =  '\n'.join('{0}/{1} {2}'.format(*x) for x in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3))
>>> print s
Modified/92 trunk/new
Modified/92 trunk
Added/92 branch
Added/92 oldpath
```

Another alternative using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
>>> from itertools import starmap, izip
>>> f = '{0}/{1} {2}'.format
>>> print '\n'.join(starmap(f, izip(list_1, list_2, list_3)))
Modified/92 trunk/new
Modified/92 trunk
Added/92 branch
Added/92 oldpath
```

If you need the string only for **printing purpose** then don't create the string, simply use `print()` function:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function  #Required in Python 2
>>> print(*starmap(f, izip(list_1, list_2, list_3)), sep='\n')
Modified/92 trunk/new
Modified/92 trunk
Added/92 branch
Added/92 oldpath
```

Comment: Hi thanks,but am getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @user3264858 You must be using Python 2.6 or earlier, I'll updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
list_1 = ['Modified', 'Modified', 'Added', 'Added']
list_2 = ['92', '92', '92', '92'] 
list_3 = ['trunk/new','trunk', 'branch','oldpath']

s = ' '.join(a+'/'+b+' '+c for a,b,c in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3))   #for separation with spaces
```

Or

```
s = '\n'.join(a+'/'+b+' '+c for a,b,c in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3))  #for new lines

[OUTPUT]
Modified/92 trunk/new Modified/92 trunk Added/92 branch Added/92 oldpath
```